# Terraform EC2 instance import - user data different

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am attempting to import an existing EC2 instance into Terraform. I have taken the EC2 instance User Data, and added it to my TF config file e.g.

```
    user_data               = <<EOF
<powershell>
& $env:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe "intl.cpl,,/f:`"UKRegion.xml`""
& tzutil /s "GMT Standard Time" 
Set-Culture en-GB
</powershell>
EOF
```

The resource imports OK, but when I run `terraform plan` I get TF wanting to destroy and recreate the instance, as a 'change' in user_data 'forces new resource'.

```
user_data: "946f756af0df239b19f86a72653e58dcc04c4b27" => "811599030dc713b18c3e35437a82b35095190a81" (forces new resource)
```

I have tried copy and pasting the user data from EC2 console into the TF file, but this is not working. Is this at all possible?

Comment: What is your objective? Do you want to be able to change the user_data without destroying the instance?

Comment: In order to import the EC2 instance, I need to ensure the 'user_data' variable matches what is currently set against the instance in AWS. I have copied the user_data exactly (well, to the naked eye...) However, when I run a plan TF thinks the UD has changed, and wants to destroy/create the instance. I do not want it to destroy the instance

Answer (score 4):

You can't copy the `user_data` value from the state, as it is an encoded string and if you copy it into the resource configuration, it'll get encoded again before it is compared to the current state, and it won't match.

But you can copy the current user data value from the Instance settings in the EC2 Console, and paste it into the `user_data` attribute of the resoure in the .tf file.

If there are multiple lines of data, you will need to replace each new-line with a `\n` in the file, as you can't use a multi-line string.

For example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance1" {
  ami = "ami-0123456789abcdef0"
  instance_type = "t4.medium"
  user_data = "setting1=value\nsetting2=value\nsetting3=value"
}
```

Note: there is a 16KB size limit on the user data in EC2, but if you're copying from EC2 to your Terraform configuration, this won't be an issue. (But it will make it difficult to read and manage, so you may want to consider storing the config in a custom image instead.)

Or, as you suggested already, if your setup supports this and you can afford to shut the instance down temporarily, remove the user data from the instance settings altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Per this github [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/4358), it looks like this is an issue with how terraform interprets the user_data as a "computed" value. There appears to be a work around.

> - First run a plan/apply cycle with your plan command including the    extra argument on your command line:
>     -target=template_file.userdata-consul. This will tell Terraform to do the minimal work it needs to update the template file, which should
>     leave your launch configuration untouched.
> - Now run plan again, and since the template_file has now already been    recreated it should interpolate the resolved template as
>     expected    into the user_data, and there should then be no diff
>     because the    "new" template rendering should be the same as the
>     "old" one.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm not sure this is the same thing (linked issue seems to be around an issue with the interpretation of the computed template file?) I tried the workaround anyhow - `terraform plan -target=aws_instance.abc` but it is still thinking that user_data has changed, and therefore the instance needs to be recreated.

Comment: @kafka Instead of copying the user_data value from EC2, have you tried copying the value that terraform detects (946f756af0df239b19f86a72653e58dcc04c4b27) and adding that to the TF config file?

Comment: I have yes, I was hoping I could grab the 'computed' value and simply sub that in, but to no avail. In the end, what I have done as a workaround, is to stop the instance and delete the User Data in the AWS console. This gets round it, but I'm lucky that I can do this I suppose (although with these servers the UD only runs on server creation)